# "for in" with unused variable

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I need to generate a string with length `x` out of characters in `y`.
My straightforward approach was

```
''.join(random.choice(y) for i in xrange(x))
```

The problem with this is that `i` is unused.
Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: The common idiom for stuff like this is `for _ in range(x)`. I believe PEP 8 actually recommends `for __ in range(x)` (two underscores instead of one).

Comment: You could use `_` in place of `i` to indicate to Python that it's a throw-away variable.

Comment: @ajcr Well, it doesn't indicate anything to Python. It just indicates that to the reader of the code because it's convention.

Comment: Agreed - a poor choice of words from me.

Comment: @dano AFAICT, PEP-8 doesn't have anything to say on the subject of naming unused variables.

Comment: @MarkReed Yes, you're right. I was thinking of the (unofficial) [Python style guide](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/style/#create-an-ignored-variable).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no better way; you can name the variable `_` to indicate it is ignored:

```
''.join(random.choice(y) for _ in xrange(x))
```

`_` is just a convention; experienced programmers reading your code will understand that it signifies 'not used' here, Python doesn't care either way.

From a performance perspective, using a list comprehension here happens to be faster:

```
''.join([random.choice(y) for _ in xrange(x)])
```

because the implementation requires two scans to first determine the output length first; this double scan means any generator expression is turned into a list anyway. Using a list comprehension here short-cuts that conversion and is faster.

Comment: The list comprehension is only faster in Python 2.x. In Python 3.x they are very close to the same speed, not that there was a huge difference in 2.x. If performance is a factor, you can get a boost by using a local variable for `choice` and avoiding two dictionary lookups on each iteration.

Comment: @kindall: sure, making `choice` a local would help. In 3.x both list comprehensions and generator expressions use a new scope, which is where the speed difference comes from in Python 2, where list comprehensions are executed in the current scope instead.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a different function from the random package, random.sample. An example:

```
import string
from random import sample
y = string.ascii_letters
x = 10
xstr = "".join(sample(y, x))
```

No need loop...

Comment: This isn't the same because it doesn't generate repetitions in the output.

Comment: Yes. Still, it depends on what what kind of sampling you want to do.  With or without replacement.